# Set the background color of a GraphView

Tags: android, android-graphview

I am attempting to set the background color of a GraphView (http://android-graphview.org).  I looked at the following StackOverflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24276370/changing-graphview-background-not-working but there was no joy.  I also took a peek at the GraphView demos at: https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView-Demos but unfortunately, none of them set the background color to something other than white.  So, what I did try was:

```
graphView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.teal));
```

and I also tried:

```
graphView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.teal));
((LineGraphView) graphView).setDrawBackground(true);
```

neither wanted to work.  Thoughts on what I need to do?

Comment: everything looks fine - perhaps the issue is elsewhere in your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks fine - that should work perfectly. It does for me:

```
graphView.setDrawBackground(true);
graphView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_green_light));
```

If you want the series to have a slightly transparent background, you can set an alpha-color value:

```
graphView.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(50, 50, 0, 200));
```

---

As an aside, if you are looking to set the background for each series independantly, I have left the details on another question:

- [Background for each series GraphView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25142689/383414)

Comment: Thank you for the Background/each series link, it was very useful to some other things I was attempting.

Comment: I thought it might be, because I found your question while trying to solve my issue, which prompted me to write the code myself.

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier, can you look at this question and give some hint. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34011301/graphview-android-color-under-graph-flickering-issue

I am facing some issues regarding `GraphView`.

Comment: @Saad it has been a year since I have worked on this library and unfortunately I am unable to help further. Good luck

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier. can you answer this question-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31260218/make-grid-lines-invisible-android-graphview